# Huffman coding tree - Priority queue malfunctioning

Tags: java, priority-queue, huffman-code

I'm trying to write a program for calculating Huffman codes for each character in a string.

Here's my code::

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class HuffmanCode{
    PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
    PriorityQueue<Node> queueCopy = new PriorityQueue<Node>();

    public void getCodes(String text) {
        int[] count = countOccurences(text);
        fillQueue(count);
        makeHuffmanTree();
        assignCodes();
        displayCodes();
    }

    public int[] countOccurences(String text) {
        int[] letters = new int[256];
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            letters[(int)(text.charAt(i))]++;
        }
        return letters;
    }

    public void fillQueue(int[] count) {
        for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if(count[i] != 0) {
                queue.offer(new Node((char)i, count[i]));
                queueCopy.offer(new Node((char)i, count[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    public void makeHuffmanTree() {
        if(queue.size() > 1) {
            Node node1 = queue.remove();
            Node node2 = queue.remove();
            queue.offer(new Node(node1, node2));
            makeHuffmanTree();
        }
    }

    public void assignCodes() {
        assignCodes(queue.remove(), "");
    }

    public void assignCodes(Node root, String code) {
        if(root.left != null) 
            assignCodes(root.left, code + "0");
        if(root.right!= null) 
            assignCodes(root.right, code + "1");
        if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
            root.code = code + "";
    }

    public void displayCodes() {
        for(Node n: queue)
            System.out.println(n.character + " -> " + n.weight + " -> " + n.code);
    }
}
```

Here's the `Node` class::

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    char character;
    int weight;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    String code = "";

    Node(char character, int weight) {
        this.character = character;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    Node(Node node1, Node node2) {
        weight = node1.weight + node2.weight;
        left = node1;
        right = node2;
    }

        }@Override
    public int compareTo(Node e) {
        if(this.weight < e.weight)
            return -1;
        else if(this.weight == e.weight)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

If you debug the above code, you'll note that the elements in `queue` are not properly sorted. If `text` is 'Mississipi', for example, then `queue` contains M,i,p,s - which is wrong (because, `M` occurred once, `i` occured 4 times, `p` once and `s` occured 4 times). It should be M,p,s,i.

**UPDATE**

I replaced my `compareTo` method with:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node e) {
if(this.weight < e.weight)
    return 1;
else if(this.weight == e.weight)
    return 0;
else
    return -1;
}
```

Now, though the ordering is opposite to what's required, the sorting is correct. This time, when I entered `Mississipi`, the `queue` contained 'i,s,p,M'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily. The queue retrieval operations poll, remove, peek, and element access the element at the head of the queue.

And for PriorityQueue.iterator()

> public Iterator iterator()
>   Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

If you want a structure which is sorted you can use a TreeSet.

Comment: @Saud "though the ordering is opposite to what's required, "  you are returning the opposite sign to what is normally used. Think `sign(this.weight - e.weight)` or `Integer.compare(this.weight, e.weight)`